# Sorting columns from different files

Tags: awk

```
File1



    Px1B-1 11
    Px1B-2 20
    Px1B-3 30
    Px1B-12 41
    Px1B-11 42
    Rx1B1  30 
    Rx1B2  35
```

File2:

```
S1B1 10
S1B2 20 
S1B3 30
Qx1B-9 40
Qx1B-8 40
Qx1B-3 45
Qx1B-1 49
Qx1B-13 51
```

In the above listing I have two data files and I have preference that I would like to make another file from that two where the conditions are:

1. Excluding a letter from a specific type of word pattern, for example: (removing x, and hyphen, except if x is attached with Q).

Px1B-1

Px1B-2

would be :

P1B1

P1B2

2. Printing would be staring with staring from P and then Q and then S, and the last numerical value in each word-column would be in ascending order. like:

   Qx1B-3

   Qx1B-1

   to

   Qx1B1

   Qx1B3

To do that I have used simple `awk` in the following way.

```
awk '($1==P1B) || ($1==Qx1B) ||($1==R1B) || ($1==S1B) {print $1}' file1 file2 > outputFile
```

How to sort out the hyphen (special text like x) and last numerical value?

**The output would be:**

```
    P1B1 11
    P1B2 20
    P1B3 30
    P1B11 42
    P1B12 41
    Qx1B1 49
    Qx1B3 45
    Qx1B8 40
    Qx1B9 40
    Qx1B13 51
    R1B1  30 
    R1B2  35
    S1B1 10
    S1B2 20 
    S1B3 30
```

Comment: What is the output you want to see?

Comment: Thanks.  I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you don't have that space preceding the text in file1. This deletes the "x" after P and deletes all "-". The sort does a "--version-sort" which works well in this case.

```
% sed -E 's/([^Q])x/\1/;s/-//' file[12] | sort -V
P1B1 11
P1B2 20
P1B3 30
P1B11 42
P1B12 41
Qx1B1 49
Qx1B3 45
Qx1B8 40
Qx1B9 40
Qx1B13 51
R1B1  30 
R1B2  35
S1B1 10
S1B2 20 
S1B3 30
```

I'm doing this on a mac. You may or may not need the "-E" flag.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly I'm looking for.  But I didn't want to exclude x from Q. Could you please have a look?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -E 's/([^Q])x/\1/g;s/-//g' file1 file2 | sort -V

P1B1 11
P1B2 20
P1B3 30
P1B11 42
P1B12 41
Qx1B1 49
Qx1B3 45
Qx1B8 40
Qx1B9 40
Qx1B13 51
R1B1  30
R1B2  35
S1B1 10
S1B2 20
S1B3 30
```

Comment: yep, question changed after multiple answers!